# US Visa for Alaska cruise

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, cruising

I'm an Indian citizen. I want to do an inner passage cruise of Alaska from Vancouver and return back to Vancouver. Do i need a US visa in spite of holding a Visa for Canada

Comment: Does the ship call in any US ports?  What does the cruise line say about visas?

Answer (score 3):

If the ship is scheduled to dock in Alaska during the cruise, to give the passengers an opportunity to debark and walk around town, then the cruise operator will check when you board if you're able to enter the United States. I'd not be surprised if the cruise operator denied boarding if you lacked a US visa.

As an Indian citizen, you will require a US visa to enter the United States. A Canadian visa does not allow you to enter the US.

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find an inside passage cruise that _doesn't_ make several ports of call in Alaska.